# Redirect after click on button and render a tab on a different route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-table

I'd like to render a Tabel component in "/game" route after clicking on a group of difficulty buttons. So the application must pass from route "/" to "/game" rendering a proper tabel depending on a difficulty state set in DifficultyButtons.js.
I manage Route components in App.js like this: `

```
      <Route path='/' render={() => <DifficultyButtons/>} />
      <Route path='/game' render={() => <Table/>} />
```

`

In file DifficultyButtons.js redirection starts from clicking on a button that set a state "difficulty" that is going to be used in file Table.js where my purpose is to render a Table proportionally to the difficulty level set. Here's Table.js:

`

```
const location = useLocation();
const rows = N*location.state;
const columns = M*location.state;


return (

    <Table responsive>
        <tbody>
        {Array.from({length: rows}).map((_, row_index) => (
            <tr key={row_index}>
                {Array.from({length: columns}).map((_, column_index) => (
                    <td key={column_index}>
                        try
                    </td>
                ))}
            </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
    </Table>
    </div>
)
```

`
Is this the proper way to render the proportional table? I'd like to understand why redirecting to "/game" is not working.
Code for redirection in DifficultButtons.js:

```
{selected ? (
        <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/game',
            state: {level:difficulty}
        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the proper way to render the proportional table?

This is a rather subjective question, but I don't see any overt issue with the way you're mapping the "2d array".

> I'd like to understand why redirecting to `"/game"` is not working.

When redirecting and passing state you are passing the difficulty level on `state.level`

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: '/game',
    state: { level: difficulty }
  }}
/>
```

but only reference `location.state` in the target route's component

```
const location = useLocation();
const rows = N * location.state;
const columns = M * location.state;
```

Since `location.state` is an object the result of the computations is likely that `rows` and `columns` are both `NaN`s.

Dereference the passed `level` value from the route state, provide safe default value for `level` if it's not passed in route state, and also a default value for `state` if a user *somehow* navigates directly to `"/game"` where the route state will be simply undefined.

```
const location = useLocation();
const { state: { level = 0 } = {} } = location;

const rows = N * level;
const columns = M * level;
```

You ask about redirecting in response to a button click, and in this case you can't just call/return a `Redirect` component from a callback and expect it to effect anything being rendered. For this you'll need to issue an imperative redirect. Use the `history` object to redirect with the appropriate state.

```
const history = useHistory();

...

// in some button's onClick handler
history.replace({
  pathname: '/game',
  state: { level: difficulty }
});
```

Comment: It seems not to work. Onclick handler is now:  const handleClick = (difficulty) => (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setSelected(true);
        setDifficulty(difficulty);
        history.replace({
            pathname: '/game',
            state: { level: difficulty }
          });
it just got redirected in "/game" but renders nothing

Comment: @Paganini I see. Can you share all of the `Table` component. And double check that you're not mixing up ***your*** `Table` component with the imported `Table` component being rendered by it. Think you could create a *running* sample codesandbox of your code that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'Redirect', you can use 'Link' from 'react-router-dom'.

```
<Link to="/game?level=difficulty" />
```

You can visit official documentation for v5 at https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link